# How to filter an Item's children based on its template?

Tags: sitecore-api

I have a navigation component that should list the current page in a hierarchy of items. I use below line of code to build navigation tree.

```
return item
       .GetChildren()
       .Select(i => new NavigationMenuItem
       (
          title: i.DisplayName,
          url: i.Url,
          children: i.IsAncestorOrSelf(current) ? Build(i, current) : null
       ));
```

Problem is some pages has other items as children I need to only return page-children when calling .GetChildren(), so how is that possible?

Comment: What about checking if item has Layout? Something like `i.Visualization.Layout != null`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case you need to filter only on the item template without worrying about other templates that are inherited by your item template you can use the following:

```
item
  .GetChildren()
  .Where(w => w.TemplateID == templateId) //filter on children's TemplateId
  .Select(i => new NavigationMenuItem
  (
   title: i.DisplayName,
   url: i.Url,
   children: i.IsAncestorOrSelf(current) ? Build(i, current) : null
  ));
```

However, if you need to filter on derived templates (templates inherited by the item template), you can use this:

```
item
  .GetChildren()
  .Where(w => w.Template.BaseTemplates.Any(a => a.ID == derivedTemplateId))
  .Select(i => new NavigationMenuItem
  (
   title: i.DisplayName,
   url: i.Url,
   children: i.IsAncestorOrSelf(current) ? Build(i, current) : null
  ));
```

Answer (score 2):

You can create a base page template and inherit this template to all pages type, then filter where the item is derived from the page template

```
public static bool IsDerived(this Item item, ID templateId)
    {
        if (item == null)
            return false;

        return !templateId.IsNull && item.IsDerived(item.Database.Templates[templateId]);
    }
```